# Trying to get property of non-object while uploading to database

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I have a script when user can clip video, then that video uploads to public folder, and now I want to upload all video data to database. But i get error like in title. Here's my code:

Controller:

```
public function clip($id)
    {
        $video = Video::where('id', $id)->first();

        $oldId = $video->id;
        $originalName = $video->original_name;
        $newName = str_random(50) . '.' . 'mp4';

        FFMpeg::fromDisk('public')
        ->open('/uploads/videos/' .$video->file_name)
        ->addFilter(function ($filters) {
        $filters->clip(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(5), FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(2));
        })
        ->export()
        ->toDisk('public')
        ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
        ->save('/uploads/videos/' . $newName);



        $data = ['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id,
            'file_name'=>$newName,
            'original_name'=> $originalName,
            'old_id' => $oldId,
        ];

         $video = Video::edit($data);
    }
```

Model:

```
public static function edit($request)
    {
        $video = new Video;
        $video->user_id = $request->user_id;
        $video->file_name = $request->file_name;
        $video->original_name = $request->original_name;
        $video->save();

        $old = $file = Video::where('id', $request->old_id)->delete();
        //$old_file = unlink($request->file('file'));

        return $video;
    }
```

What should I edit?

Comment: what is the error?? Please update your information with more details.

Comment: Please ALWAYS show us the FULL Error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're passing array, you need to use `$request['user_id']` syntax instead `$request->user_id`. You're getting the error because you're trying to treat the array as an object.

But since you have prepared array here, just use create method:

```
public static function edit($data)
{
    $this->destroy($data['old_id']);

    return $this->create($data);;
}
```

Don't forget to add [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment) array to your model to make it work.